# PHP + cURL - send POST with all isset in page fields

Tags: javascript, php, forms, curl, cookies

I have a website, for example https://example.com/login.ctl :

```
<form name="log-in" method="post" action="/other-site.ctl" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="hidden" name="TOKEN" value="5669061a39691728a3f580db0c6e7685">
    <input type="text" name="number" tabindex="1" value="" id="EnterNumber">
    <button type="submit" tabindex="4" name="submit">Continue</button>
</form>
```

And I will try to send POST with cURL:

```
$CURL_OPTS = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20131011 Firefox/23.0'
);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, $CURL_OPTS);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com/login.ctl');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");

$loginData = array(
    //'TOKEN' => '', //I DON'T HAVE THIS VALUE!!
    'number' => $costumerID,
    'submit' => 'Continue',
);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $loginData);
$login = curl_exec($curl);
```

Problem: I don't know the value of field TOKEN, but I must send it. How to do it?
Should I reload page example.com/login.ctl for changing TOKEN value.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Its not clear.

Comment: Currently I try to send POST to page with form, but I don't know value of TOKEN field. I must to send it. Do you understand? :)

Comment: you do not know how to read post values from form?

Comment: I don't know. Remember, refresh / reload page with form = new value of TOKEN field. Can you help me?

Comment: In the above form you have shown value for token.

Comment: Okay, I know, but how to read value of token from form and send POST by one connection / request cURL?

Comment: use $_POST to read the value from form post.

Comment: Make one request to download the form and extract token value from it. Then make another request sending out the form, when you know the token. If that form gets rejected, you most likely forgot to include some cookies from the server.

Comment: Thanks @David162795 - problem lies in cookies.